# How Free and Initial algebras relate?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I was wondering what is the precise relation between initial $F$-algebras and free $F$-algebras. These concepts seem very similar, as initial algebras can be used to define recursive constructions over a functor $F$, and similarly free algebras can be used to construct expression trees.

Just to give more context, I was trying to code a Free Monad over a functor F, and I realized that my implementation worked using concepts of fix and unfix from initial algebras, as well as catamorphisms.

This discussion can be seen in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/kikw8u/comment/ggx7a54/). I didn't grasp everything said in the link, but from what I understood, given a functor $F$, consider, for example, the functor $Free$ that defines free monoids. Thus, $Free F$ would be the free monad over $F$. Now, the post then claims that $(Free F \varnothing, fix)$ would be the initial $F$-algebra.

The discussion ends with the assertion " any free object is initial in the corresponding comma category". Which I don't quite understand.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Free algebras have (by their very definition) "very rich" hom-sets *to* other algebras. Initial algebras by definition admit exactly one arrow to any other algebra. In some way, initial algebras are rather very much opposite to being free!

Comment: Perhaps you can add some more detail as to what `fix`, `unfix` and `catamorphisms` are, but I suspect they might reappear simply because they are useful (categorical?) concepts.

Comment: In the category of F-Algebras, the initial algebra together with the catamorphism can be used to define recursive structures over F and to apply algebras to such recursive structure. In a sense, the free monad over F does something similar.

Comment: The following link has a discussion on this, but I did not understand the answer.

https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/kikw8u/what_is_the_relationship_between_free_monads_and/

Comment: Can you expand on "In a sense, the free monad over $F$ does something similar"? Can you add the definition of free monad over $F$ to your post (perhaps you're thinking about the way it is constructed?), and explain how you think there is something similar happening?

Comment: In the examples of groups or rings, for instance, the initial algebra is the free algebra over an empty set of generators.